# Replace whitespace in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to replace space in my column. I tried:

```
update x set y= REPLACE(y, ' ' ,'')
update x set y= REPLACE(y, CHAR(160) ,'') --SQL ERROR CHAR TOKEN UNKNOWN
update x set y= REPLACE(y, '\u00A0' ,'')
update x set y= REPLACE(y, '\xA0' ,'')
update x set y= REPLACE(y, '\xC2' ,'')
```

But none of them are working. The column is `CHAR CHARSET SET WIN 1250`

To be more precise, the value I got is for example

```
1 234
```

and should be

```
1234
```

Comment: Please specify **how** this is not working, demonstrate it using a [mre]. If this is about whitespace at the **end**, it is behaving as expected, because a `CHAR` is padded with spaces up to the declared length, as required by the SQL standard, so replacing whitespace at the end has no effect, because a `CHAR` is space-padded. Your second example doesn't work because it is a syntax error (what does replacing datatype `CHAR(160)` with empty space even mean?). Your last three examples don't work because Firebird doesn't have such character escapes, so it replaces those literal strings.

Comment: I've edited question, however example is to replace `1 234` with `1234` and my replace method says it processed all the rows but nothing happens

Comment: What is the result of `ASCII_VAL(substring(y from 2 for 1))` for that row?

Comment: `ASCII_VAL(substring(y from 2 for 1))` for that value is   `-96`

Comment: you have to commit transaction and refresh data.

Comment: Try `REPLACE(y, x'A0', '')` or `REPLACE(y, ASCII_CHAR(160), '')`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yup, so basicly it was all about i typed CHAR (type) instead of ASCII_CHAR thank You very much!

Comment: Yes, I realized that when I typed it, I hadn't made the connection at first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case - as hashed out in the comments - you need to use the [`ASCII_CHAR`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-ascii-char) function:

```sql
REPLACE(y, ASCII_CHAR(160), '')
```

or, when using Firebird 2.5 and higher

```sql
REPLACE(y, x'A0', '')
```

Your last three options don't work, because Firebird doesn't have such character escapes. The closest you can come is using the [binary string literal](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-hexstrings) introduced in Firebird 2.5.